# How to throw data at Salesforce and have Salesforce catch it

Tags: rest-api, integration

I am very new to Salesforce, and I need to be able to simply hand something like a CSV, JSON, or XML to a Salesforce I am not a user of.

Right now, these are loosely the steps I believe need to be taken:

1. Get API only user account created for me.
2. Get API calls working to Salesforce from that user
3. Set up some sort of bucket to hold the data dumps
4. Pull from db tables and drop data into CSV, JSON, or XML to be sent to Salesforce

Please correct me if I am off track at all on those steps.

However, when it comes to these high-level steps, I'm not actually sure on how to proceed on any of them. I have a Salesforce 30 day trial right now to get a feel for what needs to happen with the Salesforce I'm integrating with.

Could anyone give me some more granular steps on how to accomplish these big steps?

Comment: Weclome to SFSE, David. Have you read any of the docs on Salesforce? I would recommend going to http://developer.force.com/ and reading some of the integration and API docs and then asking more targeted questions.

Answer (score 5):

The developer.force.com site has everything you need, start at the [data integration page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Integration).